# Creating ionic resources for iOS doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm preparing my ionic app for an update in the iOS app store but I'm really stuck at the moment because generating resources using `ionic resources` doesn't work anymore.

After running the command in the terminal it starts uploading the resources I put into the folder, then tells me uploading was sucessfully completed and then freezes completely. Android and iOS folders get created, also the icon and splash folder, but then nothing more happens.

**What I tried so far:**
- replacing the icon.psd and splash.psd within the resources folder
- resetting the ionic state using `ionic state reset` (which completely removes the platforms and adds them again) + adding the official icon and splash templates from the ionic website

**Versions used:**
- Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
- Ionic Version: 1.1.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.5
- ios-deploy: 5.0.1
- ios-sim: 5.0.1
- Mac OS X Yosemite
- node: 0.12.7

Everything works quite fine on windows for generating android resources.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Not a real answer, but you could try to use local alternatives, for example [cordova-icon](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon/) and [cordova-splash](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a good workaround for now, but there's hopefully a way to fix this issue.

Comment: I created this repo to automate both icon and splash screen generation https://github.com/dericeira/Icon-Splash-Resize

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems. It has something to do with the way the .png is saved.

Try passing the file through https://tinypng.com/. It has worked for me several times.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and setting the PROXY environment variable solved the issue:

```
set PROXY=http://<proxyUrl>:<proxyPort>
ionic resources android --icon --force
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When I had the same challenge with `$ ionic resources`, I had saved my `icon.png` and `splash.png` using the png24 format, when I changed to png8 the command worked and generated the icons and splash screen files, you can give it a try and it could work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use offline alternative binary that does the same job without internet plus it supports cross platform

https://github.com/harshzalavadiya/ionic-resource-generator

p.s. i am author of this tiny app

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. For fixed:

- create new project "ionic start projectX sidemenu"
- Copie and paste folder www for new project fodler
- Add plugins use in older project
- Compile new project
- make resources and done!