# ionic resources generates a bordered icon on ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

So, usually I used the oh so awesome `ionic resources` command which would generate all the needed icons and splash screen sizes for both iOS and Android.

However, now that I did the same as usual (using the icon.psd and splash.psd files linked to from the official docs) I got the "bordered" icon (the calculator one) like this:

[image]

Did someone experience the same issue? How did you solve it?

Please note that my question is not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973261/creating-ionic-resources-for-ios-doesnt-work-anymore) since in my case it does work, just not as expected (well, not anymore at least). Also, I should mention that this (bordered icon) is the same in all the Simulators that I tried and on my actual iPhone device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" was that when I was creating the image from the template that Ionic offers on [their official site](http://code.ionicframework.com/resources/icon.psd), I placed it within the borders, leaving a certain padding around the image "transparent". This "transparent" part, once converted to png became black and that's where this black area comes from.

TL;DR: when creating an image from the official icon.psd template fill all the available image area.