# Splash screen and icon is not generating for Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using the Ionic 2 resource generator to generate the icon and splash screen for my mobile app. I have two images in resources folder; `icon.png` and `splash.png`.

I'm using the following commands to generate the resources:

```
ionic resources --icon
ionic resources --splash
```

I can see it generates icons for both iOS and Android.

[image]

And it's working for iOS without a problem. However I cannot see the icon or splash screen on Android devices. What could I be missing here?

My ionic version is `CLI v2.1.4`.

Comment: Im not 100% sure but in native Android, file name should not contains `'-','~'` and capital letters in the resource.

Comment: You have active splash screen in android and You have to set the icons and splash screen images in config.xml

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Works for iOS but not for Android. I was on CLI v2.1.4, updated to 2.1.17 and didn't work. You found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting your android folder in the resources,run the command cordova prepare android and regenerate the resources, 
Also check to make sure your files are not too big, check out the response in the question that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973261/creating-ionic-resources-for-ios-doesnt-work-anymore/37032072#37032072)

Comment: thanks for the answer , but unfortunately it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent new version of Ionic CLI that targets this problem. Update with:

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```

Make sure your image is on the following format:

**icon.png**: 1024x1024

**plash.png**: 2208x2208

Finally you can just run

```
ionic resources
```

No need for the flags.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Franco, unfortunately it didnt work. However I'm following this issue now on github according to which number of ppl has the same issue https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1166#issuecomment-260138784